# CurrentThread.CurrentCulture showing wrong information

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I launch my website, my belgian customer get de currentculture of Netherlands.
Using this code `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString()`

In my web.config I have added this rule

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="auto" />
</system.web>
```

I'm trying to save either the Country name (eg. Belgium, Netherlands, France, ...) or the culture (eg. be-NL, nl-NL, fr-FR) into a database based on the location of the client.

Problem is that some countries, like Belgium, are just never found.
I made sure that the IP is situated in the country that I expect it to be in via whatismyipaddress.com

Comment: What wonko79 is saying is that you haven't told us anything about your *problem*. Be more specific about what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no neutral belgian culture. The neutral culture for Belgium is `nl` (Netherlands). If you need to distinguish between belgian and netherlander culture, you need to get the specific culture - `nl-BE` for Belgium and `nl-NL` for Netherlands, respectivelly. This is similar to the way `en-US` and `en-GB` are specific cultures of the english language. If your user's browser only has the neutral culture defined, you're out of luck. If he has `nl-BE` as his local culture, g.pickardou's answer might help. Also note that the values of culture and UI culture can be a nonsensical combination, for example, on my computer, I have a `CurrentCulture` of `en-GB`, and `CurrentUICulture` of `en-US`. To make this even crazier, my browser has a local culture of `cs-CZ`, so a server running on my computer can get any of these possible cultures depending on the current context.

EDIT: Based on your question update, you have the wrong idea of how `CurrentCulture` works in ASP.NET. It has nothing to do with your IP address, it's only about either server settings or user's browser settings. You could of course do an address lookup by overriding `InitializeCulture`, but that's usually a bad idea. Also, as I said, there is no neutral belgian culture - `be-NL` doesn't exist. In fact, `be` is the neutral culture of Belarus.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
 <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```